# Passing an array of strings into a function from Web3js fails

Tags: web3js

I have the following function in my contract:

```
  function proposeMedia (string[] memory addresses) public {
    require(block.timestamp < expires);
    require(hashCompareWithLengthCheck(status, 'open'));
    require(payable(msg.sender) == platform);
    reporter =  payable(msg.sender);
    mediaAddresses = addresses;
    status = 'proposed';
  }
```

I can send an array of strings to the contract via Remix, which works fine. But it errors when I pass the array via Web3js, like this:

```
const addresses = ['media1', 'media2']
await contract.methods.proposeMedia(addresses)
  .send({
    from: accounts[2],
    gas: '8000000'
  })
```

Am I missing something about the way Web3 passes string arrays?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was just that I'd left a check from a previous iteration in here and it was causing the function to revert.

`require(payable(msg.sender) == platform);`